# Spring Boot Async thread Not completing the Task

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, web-crawler, spring-async

I have been working on a crawler where I have to make 1000+ request on some particular server. So far It was working nicely. But now the async task is not getting completed. Here is my sample code.

```
  private static CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

  private String getContent(TaskUrl taskUrl, String hostname, int port,
      Map<String, String> basicHeaders) {
    String uri = taskUrl.getUrl();

    HttpHost proxyHost = new HttpHost(hostname, port);
    RequestConfig.Builder reqconfigconbuilder = RequestConfig.custom();
    // in case proxy are slow to fetch data timout can be increased to 7 sec. Any longer than that might make a negative impact
    reqconfigconbuilder.setConnectionRequestTimeout(5000);
    reqconfigconbuilder.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    reqconfigconbuilder.setSocketTimeout(5000);
    reqconfigconbuilder = reqconfigconbuilder.setProxy(proxyHost);
    RequestConfig config = reqconfigconbuilder.build();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
    if (basicHeaders != null) {
      for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : basicHeaders.entrySet()) {
        httpget.addHeader(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
      }
    }
    List<String> userAgentList = CommonConstant.getCustomUserAgent();
    int in = StringUtils.getRandomIntegerBetweenRange(0, userAgentList.size() - 1);
    httpget.addHeader("User-Agent", userAgentList.get(in));
    httpget.setConfig(config);
    logger.debug("Now executing ");
    try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget)) {
      logger.info("Status code for url : {} {} with port : {} with host : {}", uri,
          response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), port, hostname);
      if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
        return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
      } else if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 404) {
        return "404";
      }
      return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      logger.error("Error for url : {} {}", uri, e.getMessage());
      return null;
    }
```

For the first 150 to 200 url its working fine.
But after some time I can see the log stuck at **Now Executing** After that nothing happens. There was time when the process just resumed itself after 1 hour. Can anyone help me in this. I don't know why it is acting like this. It should not stop before it complete the task. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Most probably you are getting block by the site. It's possible that your HTTP client w8 forever for the TCP handshake to be completed. Can you take the TCP dump and share it here? It's also possible that you ran out of the available TCP connections or file descriptors for your process, though it's less likely to happen.

Comment: Thanx for the comment @rxn1d but I have already mentioned the connection and socket timeout for 5 sec. If there is no response from the server then connection will automatically gives a connection time-out error.